# How to change \textwidth between section and subsections

Tags: width

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{first section}
\lipsum[1-1]% in section, \textwidth = x

\subsection{first subsection}
\lipsum[1-1]% in subsection,  \textwidth = y

\begin{description}% \textwidth = z
  \item{one} text
  \item{two} texts
\end{description}

\subsection{second subsection}
\lipsum[1-1]% in subsection,  \textwidth = y

% how to exit from subsection but remain in section
\lipsum[1-1] % in section, \textwidth = x

\end{document}
```

As shown above, how to change textwidth of different section, subsection, subsubsection, description etc.

(I don't know what tags to give, basic tex question related to textwidth)

Comment: you do not want to change textwidth, that is part of the page layout affecting page header and foot etc, to change the margins within the text you can use a latex list environment setting, eg the standard quote environment or the adjustwidth environment in the answer given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the environment `adjustwidth` from  the `changepage`-package. It lets you adjust your textareas left and right edges.  The code below will make the left edge 1cm shorter, and the right edge 2cm short. If you want to increase the width, just use negative values. At the end of the environment, the change is of course reset.

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{2cm}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{adjustwidth}
```

**EDIT**

I've created a new environment, called `indentLevel`, which takes one input, an integer of how many levels of indentations you want. I've included two different codes for this one, one simple which only adds the space of the length `\parindent` for each specified level of indentations, and only for the left hand side. This one is currently disables, but just uncomment the line in the environment, and comment the other one. If using the simple method, you don't need the helper macros ndentRight`and`indentLeft`.

I've also added a different approach, where you can customize each level of indentation, both left and right side. To change the settings, you change the lengths specified in the helper macro `indentRight` and `indentLeft` for the levels you want.

#### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\indentLefts}[1]{%
\ifcase#1
%Indentlevel 0
  0pt
\or
%Indentlevel 1
  1\parindent
\or
%Indentlevel 2
  3cm
\else
%Indentlevel 3
  4cm
\fi
}
\newcommand{\indentRight}[1]{%
\ifcase#1
%Indentlevel 0
  0pt
\or
%Indentlevel 1
  1\parindent
\or
%Indentlevel 2
  3cm
\else
%Indentlevel 3
  4cm
\fi
}

\begin{document}
\newenvironment{indentLevel}[1]
  % {\begin{adjustwidth}{#1\parindent}{0cm}}% Simple
  {\begin{adjustwidth}{\indentLefts{#1}}{\indentRight{#1}}}% More customizable
  {\end{adjustwidth}}


\section{first section}
\lipsum[1-1]% in section, \textwidth = x


\begin{indentLevel}{1}
  \subsection{first subsection}
  \lipsum[1-1]% in subsection,  \textwidth = y
  \begin{indentLevel}{2}
    \section{indentation 2}
    \begin{description}% \textwidth = z
      \item{one} text
      \item{two} texts
    \end{description}
  \end{indentLevel}
\end{indentLevel}

\begin{indentLevel}{3}
  \subsection{second subsection, five indentations}
  \lipsum[1-1]
\end{indentLevel}
\lipsum[1-1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: is it possible to predefine adjustwidth with section, subsection... instead of changing every time?

Comment: @Mr.EU I've edited the post.